# why this pagination counter is always showing total number of records?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, pagination, will-paginate

I have a user model and image model and having has_many relationships.
I have 18 records in images table. Now thing is:

```
 @images = @user.images.paginate(:page => params[:page],:per_page=> 12)
 p @images.count //output is always 18
```

Number of images is 18, always

For first page is 18 then for second page is again 18. Why is it so? It should be 12 for first page and then 6 for second page.

*PS: It showing only 12 and 6 records but counter is not proper. I want to get number of records on that page only. Basically for last page (considering order by id DESC) counter my vary from 1-12 and I am interested in that counter.*

Comment: I suspect you may have a `counter_cache` defined on `belongs_to :user` that is caching this count. No exact idea though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What does length return? Count is going to hit the db,

```
logger.debug @images.length
```

Try this instead? I think it will work better with paginate

```
@images = Image.where(:user_id => @user_id).paginate(:page => params[:page],:per_page=> 12)
```

Comment: Cool.. worked.. I got the thing now...Got to know the difference from will_paginate plugin code..

Comment: Btwn count will not hit the db cause Image.count will hit the db. Please confirm it.

Comment: try it in rails console, I am 95% sure it will hit the db `rails console User.last.images.count => SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "images" WHERE "images"."user_id" = xxxx`

Comment: dude images = user.images.paginate(:page => params[:page],:per_page=> 12) and then images.count will not hit DB.